# Recent Azure Function Upgrade Broke WebP Decode back to bitmap using libwebp.dll

Tags: azure, function, webp

I recently discovered that a call to this

> [DllImport("libwebp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "WebPGetInfo")]
>   public static extern int WebPGetInfo(IntPtr data, uint dataSize, out int width, out int height);

is broken, the call should have return width and height, but with the new azure function upgrade the width and height are always zero from the azure function call when running both locally and in Azure cloud.

However the same WebP wrapper code works perfectly fine for a dotnet core web api project.  I noticed that the recent Azure function upgrade changed func.exe from 32bit to 64bit.  I am not sure if this has anything to do with it, because the dotnet core web api project works in both 32 and 64 bit, but the azure function app are broken for both 32bit and 64bit.

Anyone encounter similar issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

Update.  My bad, I accidentally changed the code to get the posted file in the azure function project.